# Issue when passing multiple arguments to an external exe program using c#

Tags: c#

I have an exe file in which I am trying to pass arguments through c#. the code is as follows

```
class Class1
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] arg;
        arg = new string[3];
        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\xxx.exe";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            arg[i]  = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg[0] + " " + arg[1] + " " + arg[2];
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

I open up a console and then write the arguments there. As soon as I am finished typing 3 arguments, I make a string out of the 3 arguments and then call `Process.Start()` with the arguments in the `p.StartInfo.Arguments` string. The exe file loads but it does not generate any output. The strange thing is that if I open the exe file from my computer and then write

> Arg1.txt Arg2.txt Arg3.txt

and press enter the exe file generates the output. However the same arguments in the same style are currently being passed through C# code and  it is not generating any output. I donot understand what I am doing wrong. There are multiple questions on StackOverflow about this, I know that, however they all suggest the same procedure as what I have done here. I have also tried giving arguments as

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"arg[0]\"\"arg[1]\"\"arg[2]\"";
```

but this also has not worked.

Comment: sorry and thanks. I have deleted the image.

Comment: Did you use `Arg1.txt Arg2.txt Arg3.txt` in your real test?

Comment: @CarlosLanderas Thanks for your time but the solution you proposed is not working. I give in "arg1 arg2 arg3" as startinfo.arguments but the exe file doesnot generate an output infact it throws an expection of invalid file name which is understandable because arg1 is a name of the file. and putting " in front of a file name will not work.

Comment: " ", is used in shell comands to gather all parameters as a block... If you use arg1 arg2 arg3, most programs will only detected the first parameter. IF you use "arg1 arg2 arg3" is is considered a block...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have accepted your answer. May be there is an issue with my external exe.

Comment: You are welcome. Try using this parameters with other exe who receives several parameters between gaps so you can try the block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + arg[0] + " " + arg[1] + " " + arg[2] + "\"";
p.Start();
```

It is recomended to use "" when you use several parameters between gaps.

**EDIT:** No "\" have to be included if you type it ok. It is the escape character. See picture below.

[image]

Comment: This will not work as arg[0], arg[1] and arg[2] are file names and putting a \ in front of them will throw an exception. The files are in the same directory as the exe file

Comment: @azmuhak, you are not writing "\" !, \ is the character to escape "" so you can insert its value to the string. Just try it

Comment: Read this article about escape sequences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: The p.startinfo.argument string returns "\"A01.inp A01.wav A01.sum\""  if I use "\"" + arg[0] + " " + arg[1] + " " + arg[2] + "\"" as mentioned in your answer.  which is not right.

Comment: I update my answer. Please write it correctly! See the image above

Comment: I have edited my question and I am using the exact same strings now. However I get "\"arg1 arg2 arg3\"" using your comment. I have uploaded an image in the question as well.

Comment: Click on  magnifying glass once you are debugging!. It will show the real output and will remove the "\". Of course it shows the escae characters. Please use the magnifying glass icon button